# observablecollection how to add the collection to Sql Table WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworks

I have a `ObservableCollection<Admissiontb>` and i want to add this list to Sql Table.

The following code only add last record! Seeking any help and thanks in advance.

```
private void AddrecordToSql(object obj)
{
    AdmissiondbEntities db = new AdmissiondbEntities();

    foreach (var item in admissiontbsColl)
    {
        db.Admissiontbs.Add(item);
       
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
    

}
```

Trying to add records from the collection to the SQL table

Answer (score 0):

You could try using addrange instead.

You need to call .ToList() on your observablecollection which is in the system.linq namespace ( using ).

Then you can do something like is explained here:

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/add-record-add-multiple-records-in-entity-framework/

```
AdmissiondbEntities db = new AdmissiondbEntities();

var addList = admissiontbsColl.ToList();
db.Admissiontbs.AddRange(addList);

db.SaveChanges();

MessageBox.Show("Done");
```